# How to split the results of kml into batch files less than 2mb with python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Hi I have a table with polygons and wants to use it in google my map. The problem is that when I uploaded the file it is 86mb. The question I want to ask, how would you approach this?

My current script reads from bigquery table and converts it to KML, however I am unable to make to batch make it to 2mb per item.
Here's the Code in python

```
#read from bq
gm=client.query(
        '''
        SELECT * FROM `tablename`  
        '''
    ).to_dataframe()

def extract_coordinates(polygon_string):
    # Use regular expressions to extract coordinate pairs
    coordinate_pairs = re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+\s-\d+\.\d+)', polygon_string)
# Splitting the coordinate pairs into latitude and longitude values
coordinates = [pair.split() for pair in coordinate_pairs]

# Formatting coordinates as [longitude, latitude]
coordinates = [[float(lon), float(lat)] for lon, lat in coordinates]

return coordinates

# Applying the conversion function to the polygon string column and creating a new column 'polygon_geojson'
gm['polygon_geojson'] = gm['polygon'].apply(extract_coordinates)

# Converting the DataFrame to GeoJSON format
geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": []
}

for _, row in gm.iterrows():
    feature = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [row['polygon_geojson']]
        }
    }
    geojson['features'].append(feature)

# Converting the GeoJSON to a string
geojson_string = pd.io.json.dumps(geojson)

# Write the GeoJSON string to a temporary file
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.geojson', delete=False) as temp_file:
    temp_filename = temp_file.name
    temp_file.write(geojson_string.encode())

# Read the GeoJSON file using GeoPandas
gdf = gpd.read_file(temp_filename)

# Create a new KML object
kml = simplekml.Kml()

# Iterate over the GeoDataFrame features and add them to the KML object
for _, row in gdf.iterrows():
    geom = row.geometry
    if geom.geom_type == 'Polygon':
        kml.newpolygon(name='', outerboundaryis=list(geom.exterior.coords))

# Define the output KML file path
kml_file = 'downloaddata.kml'

# Save the KML file
kml.save(kml_file)

# Download the KML file
files.download(kml_file)
```

How do I split the files into 2mb kml so that I can read it in my map google? Is there a better way to visualize this output? It's so troublesome converting it.